# Class object pointer won't assign to string

Tags: c++, string, class, object, pointers

I am attempting to assign a pointer to a value like so

```
    string name;
    XMLSerial * ptr;

    if(name == "Armor")
    {
         ptr = &name;
    }
```

Name is initialized earlier. XMLSerial is a class that I have written. I am trying to deserialize some XML into objects. If the name is one of the classes or objects that I have defined, I want the XMLSerial object pointer to create space for the object.

The error i'm getting is `cannot convert std::string* {aka std::basic_string<char>*} to XMLSerial* in assignment`.

Comment: What do you expect the above code to do?  Why would you want to point to a `string` with a pointer to a fundamentally different type?

Comment: You can't deserialise XML just by assigning a pointer `T1*` to a pointer `T2*`.

Comment: You should explain to us why you think it *should* compile, because it seems obviously wrong to me.

Comment: Oh I know why it won't compile. I understand the error, I just don't know how to fix it. I was trying to avoid posting a mile of code. Before this code, the program reads in the xml file one char at a time and then once it hits the end bracket, the name value is set. Then I need this pointer to compare the name to the names of the classes I have to handle and construct a new one if the name matches, assigning it to the pointer I passed in to the function.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted should fail exactly in the way that you describe. It is difficult to know exactly where you've gone off the rails, but your XMLSerial might have an `operator=(std::string)` that you are trying to use.

If that is the case, replace your code with:

```
string name;
XMLSerial xml;

if(name == "Armor")
{
     xml = name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `XMLSerial` object can be constructed from a `string`, this will work.

```
string name;
XMLSerial * ptr;

if(name == "Armor")
{
     ptr = new XMLSerial( name );
}
```

**Edit:**

And, as commented, dealing with pointers and `new`/`delete` come with their own responsibilities.

Comment: Let's be careful about throwing `new` out there without further information, in this case, I think.